# @RequestMapping not working in tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications

I have this controller. When I hit /person/list I get 404. Any clue?
How do I debug?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping(value="list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Person> getPersons() {
        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way will be to change the log level to DEBUG/TRACE and see what comes up in the logs - if the control is reaching the Spring layers (DispatcherServlet down), then the logs should clearly indicate what is going wrong.

If just the logs doesn't help, another approach could be to debug the Spring flow itself - I normally put a breakpoint in the `DispatcherServlet.doDispatch()` and follow the flow through the stack